# OpenGL - render to texture - read data to CPU - data are upside down

Tags: opengl, textures

I am using render to texture and I want to read data back to CPU side of the program. I am using PBO to do this. However, if I save content of texture to the file, data are vertically flipped (upside down). Is this a normal behavior, or I have something incorrect?

PBO init:

```
glGenBuffers(1, pboID);

glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, pboID);
glBufferData(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, texture->info.rawDataSize, 0, GL_DYNAMIC_READ);

glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, 0);
```

PBO readback:

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, texture->GetRenderTarget()->GetFrameBufferID());

glReadBuffer(texture->GetAttachement());

glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER_ARB, pboID);
glReadPixels(0, 0, texture->info.width, texture->info.height, texture->info.glFormat, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER_ARB, pboID);
void * textureData = glMapBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER_ARB, GL_READ_ONLY_ARB);

//save tetxure data to file

//unlock PBO and FrameBuffer
```

I know that texture coordinates are "flipped" in comparison to DirectX, so during rendering on the screen, I am flipping the y-coordinate as well (`y = y - 1`). But how to download texture data "non-flipped"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[glReadPixels](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glReadPixels.xhtml):

> glReadPixels and glReadnPixels return pixel data from the frame buffer, starting with the pixel whose **lower left corner** is at location (x, y), into client memory starting at location data.

(My emphasis)

So yes, in OpenGL it is perfectly normal and expected behaviour for the bottom-left to be the origin.

Note that when specifying textures, since both glTexImage/glTexStorage and texture coord specification use bottom-left-is-origin, in most use cases they actually cancel each other out and you can use the same texcoords as in Direct3D.